# Partition function of a photon gas

Tags: photons, partition-function

I am trying to calculate the partition function of a photon gas. The book I'm currently following is "Thermal Physics by Garg, Bansal, and Ghosh"

It does the following:

The parition function is

$$Z = \sum_{n_i=0}^{\infty}\exp[-\frac{n_1 h \nu_1}{k_BT}-\frac{n_2 h \nu_2}{k_BT}-...]$$

$$=\sum_{n_1=0}^{\infty}\exp(-\frac{n_1 h \nu_1}{k_BT}) \sum_{n_2=0}^{\infty}\exp(-\frac{n_2 h \nu_2}{k_BT})...$$

$$=\prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1 - \exp(-h \nu_i/kT)}$$ by using infinite series.

$$\ln Z = - \sum_{i=0}^\infty \ln(1 - \exp(-h \nu_i/kT))$$

This much is fine, but then it says exactly this:

> Note that the summation is over all single photon states. Therefore, we have to multiply the expression on the right hand side by the number of states in volume $V$ and in the frequency range $\nu$ to $\nu + d\nu$. You may recall that this number is $\frac{8 \pi V \nu ^2 d\nu}{c^3}$. Hence, on replacing summation by integration and multiplying by the number of states, we get:
>
> $$\ln Z = -\frac{8 \pi V}{c^3} \int_0^{\infty} \nu ^2 \ln(1-\exp(-h \nu/kT) d\nu$$

This last step is difficult to understand. The summation is over $i$, which is an index to designate separate frequencies of photons. This is not over states so that I could multiply by D.O.S function. Also, why would we multiply it here? The quantity is not even $Z$, it is $\ln Z$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index $i$ labels the distinct *normal modes* of  cavity in which the photons are confined  rather than the *frequencies*. There can be many modes with the same frequency.  The normal modes are solutions of the classical Maxwell field equations.   Modes, frequencies, and quantum states are  different things.

Comment: Okay, I understand that a mode is associated with a frequency. When you say that quantum state is different from normal mode, do you mean that the photon gas system is made up of many different normal modes? And we can consider them separately?

Comment: How can there be many modes with the same frequency? What makes them different then? Phase? Then what limits the number of modes allowed with the same frequency?

Comment: Just compute the solutions of Maxwell's equation i a  cube with conducting walls. Obviously, because of the symmmetry, for any allowed frequency there will be at least  six  modes  because the  wave vector can be in either $x$, $y$ or $z$ direction, and there are two polarizations. Each mode can be occupied by any number of photons, so the mode and the occupation number define the quantum state.

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much!